# How to Reload a Scene without reloading the random generated index?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

So, Im making a game that when the certain level was started it was randomly generating an index to clone a prefab. My objectives is  when the player pressed the 'try again' button I need to reload the scene but still it needs to clone the previous prefab (which is got by index, and the index will generate randomly once the scene was started. What is the best way to do in implementing a Try Again button? when the game was randomly generated.

This is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class RandomControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<GameObject> prefabBG = new List<GameObject>{};
    GameObject newObject;
    public static int randomIdx = -1;
    public static bool isCloned = false;

    public void Awake () {
        GenerateRandom ();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        isCloned = false;
    }

    void Update(){

        GenerateRandom ();

    }

     void GenerateRandom(){
        if (randomIdx == -1) {
            randomIdx = Random.Range (0, prefabBG.Count);
        }
        if (randomIdx > -1 && isCloned == false) {
            Destroy (newObject);
            GameObject randomBG = prefabBG [randomIdx];
            newObject = Instantiate (randomBG) as GameObject;
            newObject.transform.SetParent (gameObject.transform, false);
            isCloned = true;
        }
    }

  void Restart(){

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of `Pseudorandom Number Generation` is that given the same context (seed), you'll always obtain the same result.
Therefor in your case you want to keep track of the seed you used (`Random.Seed`) and feed it back to the generator when you need that level again.

If the scene is reloaded, you need to either serialize the seed, or call the following method on a gameobject that will keep it in memory:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(obj);
```

Comment: I get that I need to serialized my seed, but How will I serialize it (randomIndx) based on my script above?

Comment: Well I don't have access to your code base so I can't say how best to do it. I usually keep some kind of controller gameobject active between scenes (with the above method) to keep seeds and other data. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

As @Augure suggested `DontDestroyOnLoad(obj)` would make your MonoBehaviour be persistent through scene loading.

If scalability is a concern in your project, I would recommend to wrap your logic inside a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). These objects are saved as Assets, which makes them independent from your scene loading.
Since you don't have access to the Update-Method in ScriptableObjects there are a few ways of achieving this "Tick-Functionality".

1. Call a Tick/Update Method in your ScriptableObject from a external MonoBehaviour.Update(). (optionally you can pass in deltaTime)
2. Use async/await Method to have a fixed tick rate;
3. Start a Coroutine for a fixed tick rate. (Note: You need to start a coroutine in a MonoBehaviour, so if you would need a reference to this class inside your ScriptableObject like `myMonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(myCoroutine);`

Both the async/await and Coroutine would recursively call themselves upon completion to achieve a continuous tick.
Let me know if you need any more details, or help.